# Python - Drop rows from a Pandas DataFrame that contain numbers

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with one column like this:

```
Value
xyz123
123
abc
def
```

I want to remove any rows that contain numbers so I end up with a dataframe like this:

```
Value
abc
def
```

I have tried

```
df = df[df['Value'].str.contains(r'[^a-z]')]
```

but I got this error:

"TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Have you tried with `df.filter` method?

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh that's not what `df.filter` does...

Comment: have you somewhere bound `df` to something that isn't a dataframe? Otherwise - what you've shown should work... what does `type(df)` show you?

Comment: I didn't bind it anywhere except where it loaded the data from a .csv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Independent from what looks like an issue with variable naming, you could be more explicit about removing only rows with numbers:

```
df[~df.Value.str.contains(r'\d')]

  Value
2   abc
3   def
```

`\d`:

> Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode
>   character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other
>   digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched (but
>   the flag affects the entire regular expression, so in such cases using
>   an explicit [0-9] may be a better choice).

Comment: The OPs code should work - the error suggests that they've assigned df to something that isn't a dataframe... So until they sort that out - this code will produce the same error... it is an alternative way of doing it though when that part of it is sorted.

Comment: Completely agree - "I want to remove values containing numbers" - using this approach makes more sense to me and is more accurate than the criteria being "not a-z"...(which isn't the same thing)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `isalpha`

```
df[df.Value.str.isalpha()]
Out[2057]: 
  Value
2   abc
3   def
```