# Removing Rows in Python DataFrame rows using conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove rows of data that I don't need after importing from files and concatenating my list of dataframes. Here is what my current DataFrame looks like:

```
                            Best Movie
0                        Movie: Orphan
1                                   2.
2                        Movie: Avatar
3                                   3.
4          Movie: Inglourious Basterds
...                                ...
2371  Movie: The Deep End of the Ocean
2372                               49.
2373         Movie: Drop Dead Gorgeous
2374                               50.
2375                         Movie: Go
```

I need to remove all rows with just the number in them so result looks like this:

```
                            Best Movie
0                        Movie: Orphan
2                        Movie: Avatar
4          Movie: Inglourious Basterds
...                                ...
2371  Movie: The Deep End of the Ocean
2373         Movie: Drop Dead Gorgeous
2375                         Movie: Go
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `df[~df['Best Movie'].str.endswith('.')]` ?  Try that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996822/python-drop-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-that-contain-numbers      check this.

Comment: is not getting only even rows a better way?

Answer (score 2):

One solution using [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

```
mask = ~df["Best Movie"].str.match(r"^\s*\d+\.$")
res = df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                         Best Movie
0                     Movie: Orphan
2                     Movie: Avatar
4       Movie: Inglourious Basterds
5  Movie: The Deep End of the Ocean
7         Movie: Drop Dead Gorgeous
9                         Movie: Go
```

**UPDATE**

To replace "Movie:" and reset the index, do:

```
res = df[mask].reset_index()
res = res["Best Movie"].str.replace(r"^\s*Movie:", "", regex=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0                        Orphan
1                        Avatar
2          Inglourious Basterds
3     The Deep End of the Ocean
4            Drop Dead Gorgeous
5                            Go
Name: Best Movie, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dani---worked beautifully. Now I just need to reset index so that the row numbering matches up with the actual number of rows and also remove the word "Movie: " from each row.

Comment: @Faisal See the update

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.loc[~df['Best Movie'].str.match('^\d+.$')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "Best_Movie": ["Movie: Orphan", "2.", "Movie: Avatar", "3."]
})
```

apply pd.to_numeric. the rows with only numbers will be converted to float and others will be marked as NaN.

```
df["nums"] = pd.to_numeric(df['Best_Movie'], errors='coerce')
```

extract rows which has text (i.e. rows marked as nan )

```
df.loc[df.nums.isnull(), "Best_Movie"]
```

Sample output

```
0    Movie: Orphan
2    Movie: Avatar
Name: Best_Movie, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. '|' is basically means or in this case

```
df[~df['Best Movie'].str.contains('|'.join(str(i) for i in range(10)))]
```