# Pandas: How can I drop rows with a column value containing a number?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to drop rows wherein a specific column value is a number. Here is my attempt -

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 'Ten'], ['nick', 'Fifteen'], ['juli', 14]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996822/python-drop-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-that-contain-numbers
df = df[~df.Age.str.contains(r'\d')]

# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

In this example the row having `Age` = 14 should get dropped.
But I get the following error -

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

Edit 1: I am really appreciative of all the quick answers. But unfortunately, my attempt didn't cover an edge case. What if the data is of this format -

```
data = [['tom', 'Ten'], ['nick', 'Fifteen'], ['juli', '4chan'], ['astha', 18]]
```

Here I'm looking for the row with `Age` = 18 to be dropped but not the row with `Age` = `4chan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `Age` column to `str` type and check if string is numeric with [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
df[~df.Age.astype(str).str.isnumeric()]
```

---

```
   Name      Age
0   tom      Ten
1  nick  Fifteen
```

Answer (score 3):

You need convert it to str 1st

```
out = df[~df.astype(str).Age.str.contains(r'\d')]
Out[22]: 
   Name      Age
0   tom      Ten
1  nick  Fifteen
```